# Qr code scanning using USB barcode scanner (1D/2D)

Tags: winforms, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm developing a system which requires to scan qr code.
I have a USB barcode scanner (which can scan barcode and qr code; I tried it and its working in notepad).

Now I want the scanned qr code to be input in textbox in windows form in visual studio.
Any code will help since I don't know what to do.

Comment: Click the textbox and scan your code?

Comment: No, like when i scan the qr code the data will be automatically inputed in textbox.

Comment: Do you think Notepad has functionality to detect barcode scanners? Notepad displays what you type on the keyboard. Your scanner is a keyboard. You scan, it types, Notepad displays, just like a textbox would. If you want the keyboard input to go to a specific textbox out of several, then make sure it's selected before you scan.

Comment: If you don't want to manually set focus on a text field, or for some reason can't, make a hidden control and set focus on that instead. Or in some way intercept keyboard entry, and store data in your text control. The important is to read from keyboard. Unless your scanner is NOT a keyboard, and you read data from it in other ways (which is also possible to do).